# Serialize Java Set as JavaScript Object using Jackson

Tags: java, dictionary, jackson, set

I have a set in Java: `Set<String> mySet = Set.of("a", "b", "c");`

Jackson serializes this to a JavaScript array `["a", "b", "c"]`.

However on JavaScript side I want to check for a value with optimal performance and using the syntax `mySet["a"]`. Thus, I want the Java Set to be serialized to a JavaScript object `{"a": true, "b": true, "c": true}`

How would you do this?
Does Jackson have an existing serializer for this that I can use with `@JsonSerialize`?

Comment: I suspect that converting `["a", "b", "c"]` to `{"a": true, "b": true, "c": true}` *in JavaScript* (a trivial thing to do) will be the efficient approach overall.

Comment: Then probably you have to go for map in java to generate key value pair.

Comment: No, Jackson does not have an existing serializer for this.

Comment: You can always create a map out of the set, e.g. `mySet .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), e -> true))`, and then serialize that map.

Comment: Yes, I could adapt the data structure before serialization on Java side or after deserialization on JavaScript side. This is always possible. However, it seemed less elegant to me than using the serialization tool itself to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> No, Jackson does not have an existing serializer for this

But this should do:

```
public class SetToObjectSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Set> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Set set, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        for (Object element : set) {
            gen.writeObjectField(element.toString(), "true");
        }
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

As alternative, one could adapt the data structure before serialization on Java side or after deserialization on JavaScript side.